# React native release mode is not getting last code updates

Tags: android, ios, react-native, build, visual-studio-app-center

I can not see last updates (like last 1 week) when I get release iOS and Android platforms.

I am using app center for ci/cd, it has same issue. It is mean, I tried on local build and remote build, result is same.

I recreated bundles.
I removed all caches.
I removed build folders.
But I couldnt find any conclusion.

In this week, I just changed rn versiyon and reverted this. Maybe it can due from that changes but I couldn't find anything about that.

React native version: v0.57.5
Repo: https://github.com/esteemapp/esteem-mobile